# Addressfields hide when I come back from review page

Tags: entities, commerce

I am facing a issue for several days & trying to resolve it but couldn't get any way through it.

At first I thought it's issue with `commerce_postal_filter` module but it's not.

So the real issue is, when ever user click back button from review page in checkout process address-fields vanish from the page.

I have 3 steps in checkout -

1. Order Summery
2. Account Info & Address(Billing & Shipping)
3. Review

Billing has got one more field "Phone Number", that doesn't go but only dynamic address-field hide.

Does anybody have clue why it can happen ?

**Note** - This is happening with Billing Profile only not with Shipping.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some other module installed interacting with these bits of the page? I don't know any reason in Commerce or Address Field that would make fields disappear from the page.

Comment: I have 230+ module installed in this instance. I am thinking to start from setting a fresh instance & add one by one module along with checking checkout process to see whether I can track the module which is interacting with it... Otherwise I don't have any clue.